# Retrieving data with firebase for Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a firebase database :

```
firebase.database().ref("/appointments").orderByChild("doctor").equalTo(doctorId).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var appointmentsData = snapshot.val();
  for(var appointment in appointmentsData) {
    if (!appointmentsData.hasOwnProperty(appointment)) continue;
    var obj = appointmentsData.appointment;
  }
});
```

If I console.log appointment or console.log appointmentsData, I get the correct value, but if I console.log appointmentsData.appointment, I get undefined.

Any idea how I can retrieve the properties and values from the object that firebase returns ?

Comment: When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. @theblindprophet's answer shows how to loop over the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `Firebase`'s built in `forEach` function. It allows you to iterate through a snapshot and easily get the key and value of each property inside that object. It could be another object or a flat value.

```
firebase.database().ref("/appointments").orderByChild("doctor").equalTo(doctorId).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // key
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        // value, could be object
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        // Do what you want with these key/values here
        ...
    });
});
```

Reference:

[forEach, Firebase 3.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach)

Comment: Thanks very much ! This should have been present in the firebase getting started guide